# how to search in sub collection with firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to search in all sub-collections in firebase

```
  return database
    .collection("students")
    .doc(/* usually I pass the student id here but want to get exams for all students */)
    .collection("exams")
    .where("score", ">=", 4)
    .get()
```

is this possible to do? is too late to change my database and store exams in one collection and students in another one. unfortunately. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search across multiple collections in Firestore you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), which queries all collections with a specific name.

So if you want to search the `exams` subcollections of all students, that'd be:

```
database
    .collectionGroup("exams")
    .where("score", ">=", 4)
    .get()
```

Comment: omg. this is awesome